# Drivers for LG G pad F 8.0 to develop on Android Studio

Tags: android, usb, tablet, drivers, lg

I am new to Android Studio having used Eclipse in the past.  I just bought a new LG G Pad F 8.0 tablet and I cannot find the drivers to make it appear as a device in Android Studio.  If anyone has any information on this it would be greatly appreciated!